# Why I cannot link the imageVew component in storyboard to the imageView property in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opencv, uiviewcontroller

I cannot link the ImageView component in main.storyboard to the imageView property in ViewController.m

below are my ViewController.h file

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//#import "opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    cv::CascadeClassifier faceDetector;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView* imageView;
@end
```

in main story board I just added a UIImageView inside the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you `control` and drag it from the storyboard to the .h file?

Comment: I delete the original ViewController file and create a new one my self, is that the reason ?

Comment: yeah, try to right click your UIImageView on the storyboard to check if it's still connected

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard select the viewController and set the class (name of your corresponding .h file) of the viewController at right upper corner in identity inspector where it says "custom class"...